# unable to display full items on screen orientation

Tags: android, orientation

I have a designed a screen for the app.

Here is my xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bghomescreen" >

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/tlmaintable"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="304dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp" 
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="60dp" >

        <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnsearchbylocation"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_bg_location" />

         <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnsearchbycuisine"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_bg_cuisine1" />


        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_marginTop="80dp">

        <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnquickbite"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_bg_quickbite" />

         <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnadvancesearch"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_bg_cuisine"/>    
        </TableRow>


    </TableLayout>



</LinearLayout>
```

when I run my app, I can see all the items in the landscape mode but when I convert it to portrait mode I can see only the first row of my table view. I am unable to see the others.

I am using screen with dimension 480x800.

can some one please help me.

Thanks

Comment: @rajeshwaran thnx rajesh. can u provide me any doc for the same. if u have any. thanx:). but rajesh i think den i have to scroll for seeing other images. cant i see all the images at a time?.. is there any way to do that?

Comment: @user2143817 you don't need doc for scrollview, set the orienation for your LinearLayout and also kept your linear layout under scrollview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way is to create a separate layout for your screen in landscape orientation.. that will solve the problem for you..

Answer (score 0):

Try add:

```
android:orientation="vertical"
```

in the LinearLayout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@drawable/bghomescreen" >
```

Answer (score 0):

Create separate layout for landscape and portrait.
for landscape you can write xml in `layout-land` folder and for vertical write same xml according portrait view with same name in `layout-port` folder.
 The layout will automatically call as you change the orientation.

Comment: thnx for the suggestion, but when i am trying to add layout-land i am getting some error

Answer (score 0):

I dont know Why that is not working I also calculate height and margin and all that but I also wonder why it's behaving like this

But I try your code in eclipse and found one alternative try this if it helps you

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:gravity="center">

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/tlmaintable"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="304dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="60dp" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnsearchbylocation"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnsearchbycuisine"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="80dp" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnquickbite"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnadvancesearch"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```